# how to setting windows phone7 device gps setting through code?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, gps

i wish to create a app in windows phone 7 which requires to get and set the device gps settings explicitly.
please help how to?
thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "set the device gps settings"?

Comment: i meant to switch on the location service of the device....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make an app that turns on or turns off the GPS, you can't.

You can only *use* the location service.

Details for using that are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location(v=VS.92).aspx

Comment: also can u help with a code for displaying a message to the user to switch on the location service.....